# Load external SWF with transparent background

Tags: flash, transparent

I have loaded an external swf into main swf using

```
var swf_load:Loader  = new Loader();
swf_load.load(new URLRequest("two.swf"));
```

I made the "main.swf" background as transparent in HTML using wmode as "transparent" and it's working fine. When the "two.swf" file loading it has the default background as white. How to make this also as transparent

thanks,
sathya

Comment: Anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your published HTML page

```
<script language="javascript">
    if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
        alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
    } else {
        AC_FL_RunContent(
            'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0',
            'width', '100%',
            'height', '100%',
            'src', 'PROJECT_SOURCE',
            'quality', 'high',
            'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
            'align', 'middle',
            'play', 'true',
            'loop', 'true',
            'scale', 'showall',
            'wmode', 'transparent',
            'devicefont', 'false',
            'id', 'PROJECT_ID',
            'bgcolor', '#006699',
            'name', 'PROJECT_NAME',
            'menu', 'true',
            'allowFullScreen', 'false',
            'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
            'movie', 'PROJECT_MOVIE',
            'salign', '',
            'flashVars', ''
            ); //end AC code
    }
</script>
```

Make the "wmode" property as 'transparent'. 
If your HTML page contain  tag content change the "wmode" property as 'transparent' in  tag.

*NOTE:* Make sure that your swf page didn't contain any backgrounds.

Answer (score -1):

Hi i got the solution in HTML page set `transparent as true`

thanks 
sathya

Comment: Can you explain this more for future visitors?  Your answer doesn't make sense without more context.